# central body frame (CBF) in STK

Tags: stk-agi

what is the difference between CBI and CBF in STK?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The difference is whether the frame's axes are non-rotating with respect to inertial (central body inertial, or CBI for short) or are rotating with the body in question (central body fixed, or CBF for short).